# if statement in SCSS on element with attribute equals to true?

Tags: css, sass

In the first div block in the *navbar* I want to do an if statement to say:

```
if (aria-expanded === true) { 
  height = calc(100vh - 75px)
} 
else { 
  height = 90% 
}
```

---

```
<nav className="navbar navbar-expand-xl navbar-side" aria-label="Side Navigation" >
     <div className={`navbar-toggler ${this.state.notification ? 'has-notification' : ''}`} data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sidebarCollapse" aria-controls="sidebarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle side navigation">
         Menu
     </div>
     <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="sidebarCollapse">
         <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
             <li className="nav-user">
                 <div className="profile-pic">
                     <i className="fa fa-lg fa-user mt-1" />
                 </div>
                 <i><span>{this.state.authenticatedUser.first_name} {this.state.authenticatedUser.last_name}</span><br />{this.state.authenticatedUser.job_title}</i>
             </li>
             <NavBar authenticatedUser={this.state.authenticatedUser} activeScreen={this.state.activeScreen} setActiveScreen={this.setActiveScreen} notification={this.state.notification} />
         </ul>
     </div>
 </nav>
```

Some of the scss for the sidebar is:

```
.navbar-side {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    height: calc(100vh - 75px);
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 100%;

.navbar {
    padding: 0;

}

.navbar-nav {
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
```

Comment: You can't do an if statement how you're expecting to, only during processing - https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/if

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use attribute selector:

```
[aria-expanded=true] {
  height: calc(100vh - 75px)
}

[aria-expanded=false] {
  height: 90%
}
```

Example:

```css
[aria-expanded=true] {
  color:red;
}

[aria-expanded=false] {
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div aria-expanded="true">True</div>
<div aria-expanded="false">False</div>
```

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. I realised I need to do this if the line 

<div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="sidebarCollapse"> 

has show added in like this 

<div className="collapse navbar-collapse show" id="sidebarCollapse">. 

How do I set the height to calc(100vh - 75px) if show has been added in?

Comment: @Michael93 this is trivial CSS `.collapse { /*your CSS here */} .collapse.show {/* Your CSS here*/}`

Answer (score 3):

This is a `CSS` issue and not `SCSS`. You can use plain-old [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```css
div[aria-expanded='true']{ 
  color:green; 
}
```

```html
<div aria-expanded='true'>has <em>aria-expanded</em> which equals "true"</div>
<div aria-expanded='false'>has <em>aria-expanded</em> which equals "false"</div>
<div>does not have <em>aria-expanded</em> attribute</div>
```

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. I realised I need to do this if the line <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="sidebarCollapse"> has show added in like this <div className="collapse navbar-collapse show" id="sidebarCollapse">. How do I set the height to calc(100vh - 75px) if show has been added in?